# changing ipc:// to tcp:// python zmq (Windows)

Tags: python, tcp, ipc, zeromq

I't trying to get a python application running on Windows and I get an ZMQError: Protocol not supported
which is because ipc is not supported on windows.
From what I have read the change from ipc to tcp protocol should be as easy as changing the string that is used in bind().

```
        master_addr = 'ipc://{0}/sailfish-master-{1}_{2}'.format(
                tempfile.gettempdir(), os.getpid(), subdomain.id)
        ipc_files.append(master_addr.replace('ipc://', ''))
        sock = ctx.socket(zmq.PAIR)
        sock.bind(master_addr)
        sockets.append(sock)
```

If i change ipc:// to tcp:// I get ZMQError: Invalid argument so I guess it is not that simple.
Could you walk me through the process of getting this fixed for windows, or tell me if I'm asking a stupid question.

You can see the full script https://github.com/sailfish-team/sailfish/blob/master/sailfish/master.py the code above is from line 250.
SailfishCFD is a Python Lattice Boltzmann (LBM) simulation package for GPUs (CUDA, OpenCL)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### ZeroMQ is transport agnostic

That means, one may pass messages irrespective of what transport-class `{ inproc:// | ipc:// | tcp:// | pgm:// | epgm:// }` is being used "under-the-hood".

That does not mean the same ( transport-specific ) addressing syntax will work in either case.

```
master_addr = 'ipc://{0}/sailfish-master-{1}_{2}'.format( tempfile.gettempdir(),
                                                          os.getpid(),
                                                          subdomain.id
                                                          )
sock.bind( master_addr )                                  # works on Linux/ipc
#   .bind( <<<tcp_addr>>> )                               # fails on "{0}{1}{2}".format-addressing"
```

Windows do not allow for using `ipc:` transport-class. Such a need-to-change will influence a bit wider  scope of your source code, as there are some additional ipc-related assumptions on addressing.

As seen in:

```
addr         = "tcp://{0}".format( self._subdomain_addr_map[nbid] ) # tcp://<ip>:<port>?
addr         = "tcp://{0}".format( self._iface )                    # ref. #104 missing ":<port>" part!
summary_addr = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:{0}'.format( config._zmq_port )     # port free?
```

### **Start with:**

framing the issue. Your code uses variable "fileName"-alike naming ( addressing ) for the IPC-pipes. There you start.

```
try:
     print                                   "DEBUG: Try to .bind() a ", master_addr
     sock.bind( master_addr )
     print                                   "     ==OK."

except ZMQError as Exc:
     print                                   "     ! FAILED:"
     # log & handle Exc details

except:
     print                                   "     ! FAILED: a non-ZMQ-related issue"
     # log & handle Exc details
```

### Port#-s:

Be sure you do **not** command zmq.bind() on Windows to touch "**priviliged**"
 / already-**used** / firewall-"**blocked**" TCP-port#-s.

Having checked these system settings & having made zmq-call(s) syntax compatible with ZeroMQ API for **`tcp://`** transport-class,

i.e.:

**`"tcp://<ip_address>:<port#>"`** `#                                    asString`

or

**`"tcp://<aDnsResolvableHostNAME>:<port#>"`**  `#                      asString`

you have it.

Comment: Good to know, you have considered it helpfull, Dimitar. You may want to know, that StackOverflow encourages users to express this by **+1** on both **Questions** & **Answers**, where user finds something interesting or important for her/his work. Do not hesitate to do so & enjoy becoming a contributing Member of this great StackOverflow Community of expertise.